# Only first slide is rendered

Tags: rendering

I do have my animation done. But I don`t know what I pressed and now when I press Animation, only the first slide(frame) is showed in the rendered window but there is no files on the output folder. No JPG or AVI or MPEG. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!!

Here is the screenshot
[image]

The image in the left side is the result of the render after clicking over the animation button. Blender rendered the first frame and then stop.

Comment: is the length of the animation properly set for the render?

Comment: What do you mean "only the first slide"? First slide of what? What is displaying in the image editor?

Comment: @David first **slide**, the first frame

Comment: @DiegoAdum  you can better help if you post your blend file or some pictures showing your render settings.

Comment: what happens if you press Ctrl+F12 ?

Comment: Exactly the same! Start renders and after completed the first frame its stop.

Comment: @DiegoAdum disable sequencer in the post_processing and try again

Comment: Same result! :(

Comment: @DiegoAdum i guess you can upload a [sample file here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) , (remove unnecessary objects and be sure the file has the same problem) add the link in your question

Comment: Done! [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=116" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/116/)

Comment: @DiegoAdum the problem is in the composting , you are combining a layer from blender_internal and a layer from Cycles ,you'll have to render the Volumetric scene first , or remove the composting and render both than pass the images through the processing

Comment: Thanks @Chebhou!! Following your suggestion I change the scene and press Animation button. the render start but only for the 2 scene. I change back the scene to the first one and hit Animation button and now is working again! It seems something was blocked!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @DiegoAdum Please write an answer so that others might learn form your experience.

Answer (score 1):

@DiegoAdum the problem is in the composting , you are combining a layer from blender_internal and a layer from Cycles ,you'll have to render the Volumetric scene first , or remove the composting and render both than pass the images through the processing.

Thanks @Chebhou!! Following your suggestion I change the scene and press Animation button. the render start but only for the 2 scene. I change back the scene to the first one and hit Animation button and now is working again! It seems something was blocked!!! Thanks a lot!!!